# Swift UITextField Border extension

Tags: swift

I'm using the following extension in order to draw blue lines around various textfields in various view controllers

```
extension UITextField{
  open override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
      self.layer.cornerRadius = 9.0
      self.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
      self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 122.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
      self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

This works perfect but now I'd like to exclude some specific textfields from this.
For example `@IBOutlet weak var dateTextField: UITextField!`on view controller class MainMenuController should have red borders, while other textfields on the same view controller should still show blue borders.
Is there a way to restrict the extension to certain textfield's?
Many thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to restrict the extension

No. So this was a poor approach all along. Instead of an extension, use a subclass.

Besides, an override in an extension is illegal. This should never have worked at all.

Plus it is illegal to override a text field's `draw` method. And even if it were legal, it would be the wrong place to do this, as you are not drawing; `draw` is called many times, to draw, but this is a single change you want to make *once* in the properties of the text field. When you write your subclass, override the text field's initializers.

So let's presume all your text fields come from the storyboard (like your `dateTextField`. Then you would write:

```
class BorderedTextField : UITextField {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 9.0
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 122.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Then use the Identity inspector in the storyboard to turn your text field from a UITextField into a BorderedTextField.

You can also use the `@IBInspectable` attribute to make it possible to set your border color as a setting in the storyboard itself. But that would be going beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Thank you Matt. Maybe I should have mentioned that I'm working at my first ab and try to find my way through Swift. The extension is working and all textfields are shown with a blue border. I'm happy for every comment which helps me to improve my Swift knowledge. How would be a subclass  look like?

Comment: Added more info.

Comment: A downloadable example is here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/a23f4ae7a2970be47069ca6d3117d39fa03e7644/bk1ch07p339additionalConfiguration/bk1ch07p339additionalConfiguration/RedButton.swift

Comment: Many thanks Matt. Lesson learned. Given that I have several textfields, is the  chance in Xcode to get a listing of all textfields and change them at once?

Comment: Sure, if you want to dumpster-dive into the XML version of your storyboard. But I wouldn't if I were you.